# My Godaddy domain redirects to another domain after pointing to the same ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain-aliasing

I have a single ec2 instance. Initially, I already have a domain(domaina.io) assigned to it, it is hosted in Godaddy. Now, I have another domain(domainb.com) and I want to point to the same ec2 instance, I do this for marketing/promotional purposes. When I added an A record for the other domain(domainb.com) and point it to the same IP of the ec2 instance, it worked but when I visited my second domain(domainb.com) I get redirected to the other domain(domaina.io). How will I do this such that the second domain(domainb.com) will not redirect to the first domain(domaina.io) and will still point to the ec2 instance?